# Help with SQL query

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables defined as follow :

Product(**IdProduct**,NameProduct,Color,Mass)
Supplier(**IdSupplier**,NameSupplier,CitySup)
Factory(**IdFactory**,NameFactory,CityFac)
Shipping(**IdProduct**,**IdFactory**,**IdSupplier**,Quantity) : the product **Idproduct** is shipped to the factory **IdFactory** by the Supplier **IdSupplier** with quantity **Quantity**

I need to get the list of IdProduct of products that are shipped to every factory in Paris (*Factory.cityFac="Paris"*).
 What is a proper approach to get this result in *SQL* ?

Comment: please tag your dbms

Comment: Use the necessary [`JOINs`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that according to your question, Supplier is not needed to get the final result.

```
select p.IdProduct, p.NameProduct, p.Color, p.Mass
from Shipping s
     inner join Factory f
         on f.IdFactory = s.IdFactory
     inner join Product p
         on s.IdProduct = p.IdProduct
where
    f.CityFact = 'Paris';
```

Comment: this is false since it will return all the products that have been shipped to Paris but not necessarily to every factory in Paris

Comment: I'm sorry? `I need to get the list of IdProduct of products that are shipped to every factory in Paris (Factory.cityFac="Paris")`

Comment: the comment between () is there just to state the name of the column, I need the products that were shipped to all factories in Paris.

Comment: And which field defines that a factory is from Paris?

Comment: Factory.cityFac

Comment: Thats what my query does. Returns all products shipped to a Paris's factories.

Comment: And that's not what I'm looking for , I need the products that are shipped to ALL factories in Paris :)

Comment: Yes, ALL products shipped to ALL factories where Factory.cityFact = 'Paris'